# How to get value of mydatepicker as formatted value in angular 2?

Tags: json, datepicker, angular2-forms

I am using `my-date-picker`in angular2 ,when i select any date from datepicker then it will give me output of datepicker in `JSON` like this 
`"effectiveDate":{"date":{"year":2017,"month":7,"day":1},"jsdate":"2017-06-30T18:30:00.000Z","formatted":"07/01/2017","epoc":1498847400}` but i want output like `"effectiveDate":"07/01/2017"` this.

**getting output** :

```
"effectiveDate":{"date":{"year":2017,"month":7,"day":1},"jsdate":"2017-06-30T18:30:00.000Z","formatted":"07/01/2017","epoc":1498847400}
```

**need output** :

```
"effectiveDate":"07/01/2017"
```

Comment: convert it to a string and use the string value

Comment: (dateChanged)="model.birthDate = $event.formatted"

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below:

```
 var dateFrom = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.ABIForm.controls['From'].value));   

var strFromDate =dateFrom.date.month+"/"+dateFrom.date.day+"/"+dateFrom.date.year;

var dateFromTransformed= this.datePipe.transform(strFromDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<my-date-picker [options]="myDatePickerOptions" [(ngModel)]="Date" (dateChanged)="onDateChanged($event)" #ngRef="ngModel" required id="Date" name="Date" ngModel> </my-date-picker>

private myDatePickerOptions: IMyOptions = {

    dateFormat: 'yyyy.mm.dd',
};

Public effectiveDate : string;
OnDateChanged(event: IMyDateModel) {
    this.effectiveDate = event.formatted;
}
```

1. Put above code in component to get the JSON date format as string.